# Python Pandas grouping DataFrame by blocks of sequential values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a large pandas DataFrame having a timestamp column, a value column, a "key" column and a column with a flag indicating end of a block (and some more actually)

```
timestamp, value, key, last_in_block
12345, 1.0, 2, False <-- start of block 1
12346, 0.5, 4, False
12347, 1.2, 1, False
12348, 2.2, 6, False
12349, 1.5, 3, False
12350, 1.2, 3, False
12351, 2.3, 3, False
12352, 0.4, 5, True
12371, 1.3, 2, False <-- start of block 2
12372, 0.9, 4, False
12373, 1.7, 1, False
12374, 2.0, 6, False
12375, 1.2, 3, False
12376, 1.4, 3, False
12377, 2.7, 3, False
12378, 0.8, 5, True
...
```

In the "key" column a characteristic sequence of values (in this example 2 4 5 6 3 3 3 5) appears identifying a data block. I would like to apply a "groupBy" statement to break the Frame into groups by blocks. Is this / how is this possible?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data =
              {"timestamp": list(range(12345,12353)) + list(range(12371,12379)),
                "value": [1.0,0.5,1.2,2.2,1.5,1.2,2.3,0.4,1.3,0.9,1.7,2.0,1.2,1.4,2.7,0.8],
                "key": [2,4,1,6,3,3,3,5]*2,
               "last_in_block" : [False]*7+[True]+[False]*7+[True]})
```

Update, answers to questions:

- I known the sequence in advance
- The sequences are complete besides very rare exceptions

Comment: Do you know this sequence in advance? Its length? If not is it always complete? Please give some context as it's currently difficult to know how this generalizes

Comment: @mozway: I enhanced the description above according to your questions

Comment: thanks for the update, if you have a flag it's easy, see below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last_in_block` to identify the groups, then use `groupby`:

```
df["last_in_block"] = np.where(df["last_in_block"].shift(), 1, 0)
df["last_in_block"] = df["last_in_block"].cumsum()
grouped = df.groupby("last_in_block")
```

`grouped.groups`:

```
{1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 2: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]}
```

`grouped.mean()`:

```
               timestamp   value    key
last_in_block                          
1                12348.5  1.2875  3.375
2                12374.5  1.5000  3.375
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a flag for the last item per block you can use a reverse [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to form the groups:

```
group = df.loc[::-1, 'last_in_block'].cumsum()
for k, g in df.groupby(group, sort=False):
    print(g)
```

Alternatively, if you didn't know the periodicity nor had a flag, you could estimate the periodicity with an autocorrelation ([`autocorr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.autocorr.html)) on the key, the periodicity corresponding to the lag with the maximum correlation:

```
lag = pd.Series({i: df['key'].autocorr(i)
                 for i in range(1, len(s)//2+1)}
               ).idxmax()
# periodicity: 8

group = np.arange(len(df))//lag

for k, g in df.groupby(group, sort=False):
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
   timestamp  value  key  last_in_block
0      12345    1.0    2          False
1      12346    0.5    4          False
2      12347    1.2    1          False
3      12348    2.2    6          False
4      12349    1.5    3          False
5      12350    1.2    3          False
6      12351    2.3    3          False
7      12352    0.4    5           True
    timestamp  value  key  last_in_block
8       12371    1.3    2          False
9       12372    0.9    4          False
10      12373    1.7    1          False
11      12374    2.0    6          False
12      12375    1.2    3          False
13      12376    1.4    3          False
14      12377    2.7    3          False
15      12378    0.8    5           True
```

Autocorrelation plot:

[image]